# Making custom test result

Tags: pytest

Is it possible to add a custom test result at same level as: passed, failed, xfail, skipped, deselected? I would like to be able to assign the custom test result during fixture setup similar to calling pytest.skip().

Alternatively, is it possible to "deselect" a test case from a fixture (i.e. during fixture setup - not collection phase)?

### My problem

I'm using pytest *not* for testing python code, but for making black box testing of different devices connected to a host PC running the pytest code. During one pytest session, I'm only testing one device, but possibly multiple interfaces (IP, RS-232, GPIO, etc.).

When launching pytest, I supply as argument a configuration file. That file specifies the IP address of the device and also which interfaces the host PC has connected to the device.
I'm using fixtures to skip tests that can not be run because either:

- The particular device does not implement the functionality of the test case
- The host does not support the functionality (physical interface) of the test case

I need to be able to distinguish between those two reasons for skipping a test case: when making a software release, I need to make sure that there are no tests that were skipped because of the host configuration.
Hence, I would like to set test result "not applicable" in the former case and "skipped" in the latter.

I could of cause specify the device capabilities on the command line and have the pytest collection phase deselect the test cases, but I really need/require/want this done at runetime. Otherwise the number of arguments for running the tests will quickly explode.

My current test results look like this:

- Device A: 235 skipped out of 468
- Device B: 445 skipped out of 468

You can see that I use the same test suite for both devices because they share much of the same functionality (I just haven't written many of the test cases validating the shared functionality).

### How would it look?

I would like to be able to mark a test "not applicable" like this:

```
@pytest.fixture
def device(myconfig):
    cfg = myconfig.get_ip()
    return Device(cfg.ip, cfg.port)


@pytest.fixture
def serial(device, myconfig):
    if not device.has_serial:
        mark_not_applicable("Device does not support: serial")

    try:
        cfg = myconfig.get_serial()
        return serial.Serial(cfg.device, baudrate=cfg.baudrate)
    except:
        pytest.skip("Host interface not defined for: serial")


@pytest.fixture
def has_alpha(device):
    if not device.has_alpha:
        mark_not_applicable("Device does not support: alpha")


@pytest.fixture
def has_beta(device):
    if not device.has_beta:
        mark_not_applicable("Device does not support: beta")


def test_serial_protocol_alpha(serial, has_alpha):
    check_serial_protocol_alpha()


def test_serial_protocol_beta(serial, has_beta):
    check_serial_protocol_beta()
```

Comment: You can always `skip` a test in a fixture based on some condition (using `pytest.skip`). Wouldn't that be sufficient for your use case?

Comment: No, my problem is I would like to distinguish _why_ it was not run: 1) The test case should never be run, 2) the test case can not run because the host PC setup is limited

Comment: Yes, I understand. I meant that you would not skip the tests of the second case for releases (in case you can detect these at runtime), so they would just fail. That does not differentiate the tests in other cases (non-release) of course, except you set a different skip message and count the messages in the output.

Comment: Ah, I get it. You're right, that could be a way out. But I'd still prefer to have a new test result type (e.g. "Not applicable").

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible - the current result types are more or less hardcoded in pytest.

Comment: Okay, I will settle with you suggestion. Thank you for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

yes it this is possible to do with the `pytest_report_teststatus(report, config)` hook.

https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_report_teststatus

We successfully use this to differentiate between test statuses and triage the test cases by failure "type".

your `conftest.py` or plugin

```py
import pytest


CUSTOM_STATUS_BLOCKED = "_blocked"

@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    """Called to create a test report for each of the setup, call and teardown runtest phases of a test item."""
    report = (yield).get_result()
    
    if report.failed and call.excinfo.typename != "AssertionError":
        # Error occurred in test case, which was not due to a verification
        # Could be that the test case code is broken. Add custom property
        # on the report to store wether the test is `blocked`.

        setattr(report, CUSTOM_STATUS_BLOCKED, True)


def pytest_report_teststatus(report, config):
    """Customizes the reporting of test statuses."""
    if getattr(report, CUSTOM_STATUS_BLOCKED, False):
        return "blocked", "B", ("BLOCKED", {"yellow": True})
```

some test module to showcase:

```py
test_one():
    """Blocked test case example"""
    raise RuntimeError("Test Blocked")


test_two():
    """Failed test case example"""
    assert False


test_three():
    """Passed test case example"""
    assert True
```

Running these test cases will report:

```
=================================== test session starts ====================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.10.6, pytest-7.2.0, pluggy-1.3.0
rootdir: /Users/me, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: html-3.2.0, metadata-3.0.0, check-2.1.2
collected 3 items                                                                          

test.py BF.     [100%]

========================================= FAILURES =========================================
_________________________________________ test_two _________________________________________

    def test_two():
        """Failed test case example"""
>       assert False
E       assert False

test.py:9: AssertionError
================================= short test summary info ==================================
FAILED test.py::test_two - assert False
========================== 1 failed, 1 passed, 1 blocked in 0.08s ==========================
```

Note the short statuses: `test.py BF.`, meaning Blocked, Failed and Passed.
Also the long summary with the test cases status bins.