# Custom Pytest Result

Tags: python, pytest

I am aware that it is possible to make custom pytest results ([Making custom test result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63631224/making-custom-test-result)), however I'm struggling to set up a new result for a test which passed.

For example (psuedo-code):

```
def test_speed():
    duration = timeit(my_function())
    if duration > 60:
        set_pytest_flag(it_passed_but_took_a_while)
```

then later in `conftest.py`

```
CUSTOM_STATUS_TIME = "_time"

@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    """Called to create a test report for each of the setup, call and teardown runtest phases of a test item."""
    report = (yield).get_result()
    
    if report.passed and call.info.it_passed_but_took_a_while:
        # Error occurred in test case, which was not due to a verification
        # Could be that the test case code is broken. Add custom property
        # on the report to store wether the test is `time`.

        setattr(report, CUSTOM_STATUS_TIME, True)


def pytest_report_teststatus(report, config):
    """Customizes the reporting of test statuses."""
    if getattr(report, CUSTOM_STATUS_TIME, False):
        return "time", "T", ("TIME", {"yellow": True})
```

Which would then allow my tests to pass, but give the user an indication that it took too long.

Noe: I'm only using duration as an example, I'd like to set my flag based off of other logic that I won't get into.

So the question is, is there anything on `report` or `call` that I can set during tests, such that I can then read them back in the hook, without raising an Exception?